# Mainpage.xaml - OnNavigateTo

Tags: silverlight-4.0, mvvm

I'm developping a Silverlight application with ViewModels.

My MainPage.xaml has a menu defined and based on someones accesslevel I want to Collapse or make vissible certain menu items.

Since the OnNavigateTo isn't available on my MainPage.xaml.cs, I was wondering on how to do this.

The menu should be changed every time a users logges in/logges out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a MenuItem for your menu, bind the Visibility to a propery in your ViewModel...

```
        <StackPanel>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Do Something" Visibility="{Binding CanDoSomething}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

The property in your ViewModel could be declared thusly...

```
public Visibility CanDoSomething { get; set; }
```

And you would toggle it with a method in your ViewModel like this...

```
private void SetMenuVisibility()
{
    if (UserIsLoggedIn)
    {
        CanDoSomething = Visibility.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        CanDoSomething = Visibility.Collapsed;
    }
    OnPropertyChange("CanDoSomething");
}
```

You would call this method whenever a user logged in or out.  This will achieve collapsing or expanding menu items in the way you stated.  Each MenuItem must be bound to a property in the ViewModel, and the ViewModel must inherit from INotifyPropertyChanged.

Secondarily, if you wanted to use the ICommand pattern, you would bind the Command property of the MenuItem to a Command in your ViewModel...

```
        <StackPanel>
            <toolkit:MenuItem Header="Do Something"  Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" />
        </StackPanel>
```

The ViewModel would declare a command like this...

```
public ICommand DoSomethingCommand { get; set; }
```

And initialize it like this...

```
private void InitializeDoSomethingCommand()
{
    DoSomethingCommand = new RelayCommand
        (
            ExecuteDoSomething,
            param=>UserIsLoggedIn
        );
}
```

I have used the 'RelayCommand' here, but any similar class will do.

The difference between these two approaches is the first will collapse the MenuItem and make it invisible to the end user.  The second will simply disable the command, but it will still be visible in a 'grayed out' state.

Comment: Hmmm, The problem is that now I manually have to refresh the browser page each time because I've used this on my MainPage...